# How to get array of objects by object and arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

For the array of object, compare with object and list array using javascript

should get the array of objects based on below conditions

1. `itemvalue and idvalue same`, from that check `arrobj cid has same codevalue` return both array of objects
2. `itemvalue and idvalue are same`, from that check if `cid not matching the arraylist` and `codevalue has value that does not  exist in arraylist`, return array of objects
3. `itemvalue and idvalue same`, from that check if `codevalue matching the arraylist` and `cid has value that does not  exist in arraylist`, return array of objects

return empty array [] if above fails

```
//data1
var arraylist = ["IN","FP", "FN"];
var arrobj1 = [
  {id:1, name: "sun", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "3456"},
  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "4567"},
  {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SP", itemvalue: "4567"},
  {id:4, name: "thurs", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2345"},
]
var obj1 = { id:5, name: "ben", codevalue: "SG", idvalue:"4567"}

Expected Output
[
{id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "4567"},  
{id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SP", itemvalue: "4567"}
]

***
//data2
var larrylist= ["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj2 = [
  {id:1, name: "sun", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "thur", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2345"},
]
var obj2 = { id:5, name: "ben", codevalue: "SP", idvalue:"2468"}

Expected Output

[]

***

//data2
var arraylist= ["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj3 = [
  {id:1, name: "sun", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SG", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "thur", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2345"},
]
var obj3 = { id:5, name: "ben", codevalue: "FI", idvalue:"2468"}

Expected Output
[
 {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2468"}
]
```

Tried

```
const result = arrobj1.filter((item) => {
  return item.itemvalue === obj.idvalue &&
    (
      !arraylist.includes(item.cid)
      || item.cid === obj.codevalue
    )
})
```

Comment: Why is there {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SG", itemvalue: "2468"} in the last example ? CID is not in the arraylist ?

Comment: Please try and explain the conditions more clearly. For example, what do you mean by, *"if codevalue and cid different list"*?

Comment: @MikeM thanks for reply, I have updated my problem statement

Comment: What does *"arrobj codevalue has same cid"* mean? `arrobj` doesn't have a `codevalue` property. What does *"codevalue not matching the arraylist"* mean? `codevalue` is a string. How could it possibly match the array `arraylist`? Please continue your efforts to express the conditions more precisely.

Comment: @MikeM thanks a lot for reply, i updated my conditions and apologies for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a clear problem statement will very often get you most of the way to a solution.  Try to say *precisely* what you mean, then try to code *precisely* what you said.

Doing that here using the OP's problem statement and examples, we get:

The goal is to filter an array of objects (`arrobj1`) to produce a another array which meets criteria relating to an object (`obj1`) and another array (`arraylist`).

1. The filter predicate is true if there's match between the prop `idvalue` of `obj1` and the prop `itemvalue` of the array element, **AND**...
2. The predicate must also (2a) find match between the prop `codevalue` of `obj1` and the prop `cid` of the array element, **BUT** (2b) this comparison is contingent on the presence of either object's prop (`codevalue` or `cid`) in `arraylist`. Specifically, if either the element's `cid` or the object's `codevalue` is in the `arraylist`, then the element's `cid` value must match the `codevalue` of `obj1`.

Restated with this sort of (laborious) precision, coding the predicate is much easier. Let's code it in bite-sized pieces...

```
// condition 1
// el is an element from arrobj1, and obj is an instance like obj1
// check if their itemvalue and idvalue (respectively) are equal
const idsMatch = (el, obj) => obj.idvalue === el.itemvalue;

// condition 2b
// el is an element from arrobj1, obj is an instance like obj1 and cidList 
// is the given list of cids (like arraylist)
// check if the element's cid and the obj's codevalue is in the arraylist
const cidFound = (el, obj, cidList) => {
  return cidList.includes(el.cid) || cidList.includes(obj.codevalue);
}

// condition 2a
// el is an element from arrobj1, and obj is an instance like obj1
// check if their cid and codevalue (respectively) are equal
const cidPropMatch = (el, obj) => obj.codevalue === el.cid;

// from 2a and 2b, make condition 2
// cidsMatch if the element isn't in the cidList, or if it is and the objects' props match
const cidsMatch = (el, obj, cidList) => {
  return !cidFound(el, obj, cidList) || cidPropMatch(el, obj);
}

// combining into a predicate
const filterPredicate = (el, obj, cidList) => {
  return idsMatch(el, obj) && cidsMatch(el, obj, cidList);
};
```

Ta-dah! Demo...

```js
// condition 1
const idsMatch = (el, obj) => obj.idvalue === el.itemvalue;

// condition 2b
const cidFound = (el, obj, cidList) => {
  return cidList.includes(el.cid) || cidList.includes(obj.codevalue);
}
// condition 2a
const cidPropMatch = (el, obj) => obj.codevalue === el.cid;

// condition 2
const cidsMatch = (el, obj, cidList) => {
  return !cidFound(el, obj, cidList) || cidPropMatch(el, obj);
}

// predicate
const filterPredicate = (el, obj, cidList) => {
  return idsMatch(el, obj) && cidsMatch(el, obj, cidList);
};

var arraylist = ["IN","FP", "FN"];
var arrobj1 = [
  {id:1, name: "sun", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "3456"},
  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "4567"},
  {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SP", itemvalue: "4567"},
  {id:4, name: "thurs", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2345"},
]
var obj1 = { id:5, name: "ben", codevalue: "SG", idvalue:"4567"}

const result = arrobj1.filter(el => filterPredicate(el, obj1, arraylist));
console.log(result);

// Expected Output
// [
// {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "4567"},  
// {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SP", itemvalue: "4567"}
// ]


arraylist = ["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj2 = [
  {id:1, name: "sun", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "thur", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2345"},
]
var obj2 = { id:5, name: "ben", codevalue: "SP", idvalue:"2468"}

const result2 = arrobj2.filter(el => filterPredicate(el, obj2, arraylist));
console.log(result2);

// Expected Output
// []


arraylist = ["IN","FI","FR"];
var arrobj3 = [
  {id:1, name: "sun", cid: "IN", itemvalue: "1234"},
  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:3, name: "tues", cid: "SG", itemvalue: "2468"},
  {id:4, name: "thur", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2345"},
]
var obj3 = { id:5, name: "ben", codevalue: "FI", idvalue:"2468"}

const result3 = arrobj3.filter(el => filterPredicate(el, obj3, arraylist));
console.log(result3);

// Expected Output
// [
//  {id:2, name: "mon", cid: "FI", itemvalue: "2468"}
// ]
```

The important point here is the method. Try to say *precisely* what you mean, try to code *precisely* what you said. I did that here, and, believe it or not, the snippet matched the expected output on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do :

```js
const result = arrobj.filter((item) =>
    item.itemvalue === obj.idvalue && (arraylist.includes(item.cid) || item.cid === obj.codevalue)
);
```

Comment: thanks, but it fails, on first data1 scenario (i.e)`itemvalue and idvalue same, if code not matching the arraylist and then every cid does not have arraylist value,`

Comment: If this is the case then the last scenario should return 2 answers.

Comment: but first scenario and last scenario are differnt