# how to retrieve the object from array of objects and arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, filter

I have array of objects and arrays.

If the array of objects has `value property same`

- and if `place` includes of  arrraylist `list` return first obj
- and if `place` is equal includes/not includes return first obj

if no above conditions return undefined; using javascript

```
var list=['SG','TH','MY']


var arrobj1=[
  {id:1, name:'userone',place:'SG', value:100},
  {id:2, name:'usertwo',place:'TH', value:100},
  {id:3, name:'userthree',place:'IL',value:200},
]
Expected Output
{id:1, name:'userone',place:'SG', value:100}

****
var arrobj2=[
  {id:1, name:'userone',place:'IN', value: 200},
  {id:2, name:'usertwo',place:'SL',value: 100},
  {id:3, name:'userthree',place:'SL', value: 100},
]
Expected Output
{id:2, name:'usertwo',place:'SL',value: 100}
****
var arrobj3=[
  {id:1, name:'userone',place:'SL', value:10},
  {id:2, name:'usertwo',place:'IN', value:20},
  {id:3, name:'userthree',place:'KL', value:30},
]
Expected Output
undefined
```

Tried

```
var result= arrobj.find(e=>{
  if((e.value === e.value) && (list.includes(e.place)){
   return e
  }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by _if the array of objects has `value property same`_? Please clarify your conditions and perhaps show us how you're trying to meet them in your code.

Comment: @PeterKA thanks for reply, means duplicate value

Comment: Do you mean: From the array elements with duplicate values, find the first whose `place` value is in the list, or (failing that) the first whose place is also duplicated in the duplicate values list?  This is another example where most of the analytical work must take place in the problem statement.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900081/how-to-get-array-of-objects-by-object-and-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @code123 ... isn't this question just another variation of ... [_"How to get array of objects by arrays in javascript"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952123/how-to-get-array-of-objects-by-arrays-in-javascript) ... where until now the OP didn't respond to an approach which enables the solution of the OP's 3 different scenarios (requirements)?

Answer (score 1):

I've added inline comments to correspond to the requirements.  I wasn't sure exactly what you meant in some cases, so I can adjust the answer if you clarify the question

```js
var list = ['SG', 'TH', 'MY']


var arrobj1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'userone',
    place: 'SG',
    value: 100
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'usertwo',
    place: 'TH',
    value: 100
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'userthree',
    place: 'IL',
    value: 200
  },
]
//Expected Output
//{id:1, name:'userone',place:'SG', value:100}

//****
var arrobj2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'userone',
    place: 'IN',
    value: 200
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'usertwo',
    place: 'SL',
    value: 100
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'userthree',
    place: 'SL',
    value: 100
  },
]
//Expected Output
//{id:2, name:'usertwo',place:'SL',value: 100}
//****
var arrobj3 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'userone',
    place: 'SL',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'usertwo',
    place: 'IN',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'userthree',
    place: 'KL',
    value: 30
  },
]
//Expected Output
//undefined

function getMatch(places, arrObj) {
  // .find will return the first item that matches the condition provided
  return arrObj.find(
    l => list.includes(l.place) // either the place of this item must exist in the list
|| arrObj.filter(arr => arr.value === l.value).length > 1) // or the value of this item must appear more than once in the list
}


console.log(getMatch(list, arrobj1));
console.log(getMatch(list, arrobj2));
console.log(getMatch(list, arrobj3));
```